# Extract text between words

Tags: oracle

I trying to extract numbers between two words distincts, but "`substr`" don't work combined with "`instr`". At least I'm not getting!

Example:

```
CODTAX  TAX_DESCRIPTION
-----------------------
1225    NCM 85444900 IPI 0% ICMS 18% CST 060 IVA 41,00% IVA EXT 51,32%
```

The extract number between "IPI " and "% ICMS" is **0** or between "IVA " and "% IVA" is **41.00**.

```
CREATE TABLE TAX
(
  CODTAX           NUMBER,
  TAX_DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
);

INSERT INTO TAX (CODTAX, TAX_DESCRIPTION)
     VALUES (1505, 'NCM 29051220 IPI 0% ICMS 18% CST 000 IVA 0% IVA EXT 0%');
INSERT INTO TAX  (CODTAX, TAX_DESCRIPTION) 
     VALUES (1258, 'NCM 85444900 IPI 0% ICMS 18% CST 060 IVA 41,00% IVA EXT 51,32%');
INSERT INTO TAX (CODTAX, TAX_DESCRIPTION)
     VALUES (2051, 'NCM 85362000 IPI 10% ICMS 18% CST 060 IVA 43,00% IVA EXT 53,46%');
```

The result must be:

```
CODTAX  TAX_DESCRIPTION                                                 IPI    IVA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1505    NCM 29051220 IPI 0% ICMS 18% CST 000 IVA 0% IVA EXT 0%            0      0 
1258    NCM 85444900 IPI 0% ICMS 18% CST 060 IVA 41,00% IVA EXT 51,32%    0  41,00 
2051    NCM 85362000 IPI 10% ICMS 18% CST 060 IVA 43,00% IVA EXT 53,46%  10  43,00
```

Comment: What result are you getting? I would use the approach you describe.

Comment: Hi Karl, the result expected is 0 for IPI or 41,00 for IVA. For each tax, i'll create one column!

Comment: The result must be:
  CODTAX TAX_DESCRIPTION        IPI IVA
  1505   NCM 29051220 IPI 0% ICMS 18% CST 000 IVA 0% IVA EXT 0%   0 0
  1258   NCM 85444900 IPI 0% ICMS 18% CST 060 IVA 41,00% IVA EXT 51,32%  0 41,00
  2051     NCM 85362000 IPI 10% ICMS 18% CST 060 IVA 43,00% IVA EXT 53,46%  10 43,00

Comment: Are you getting an error, wrong result, sething else?

Comment: Hi, Karl! I was not able to fit the select only, and the results that could not were those who had hoped. With the examples you have sent to me, I could now reach the goal. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a combination of INSTR and REGEXP_SUBSTR.

```
SELECT A.*,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (A.TAX_DESCRIPTION,
                      '\d+,?\d*',
                      INSTR (a.tax_description, 'IPI')) IPI,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (A.TAX_DESCRIPTION,
                      '\d+,?\d*',
                      INSTR (a.tax_description, 'IVA')) IVA
  FROM TAX A;
```

INSTR is used to find the first position of IPI and IVA. It is then used in REGEXP_SUBSTR function to specify the starting position.

The regex pattern,

- \d+ matches one or more digits.
- ,? matches zero or one comma.
- \d* matches zero or more digits.

Comment: Thank you! The command was lean, but regular expressions are a little complicated. You can tell if there is any site with legal references to learn how to use regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

`substr` and `instr` variant:

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6041/6)

```
select
  codtax, 
  tax_description, 
  (
    trim(substr(
      tax_description,
      instr(tax_description, 'NCM') + length('NCM'),
      instr(tax_description, 'IPI') - 
        (instr(tax_description, 'NCM') + length('NCM'))
    ))
  ) ncm,
  (
    trim(substr(
      tax_description,
      instr(tax_description, 'IPI') + length('IPI'),
      instr(tax_description, '% ICMS') - 
        (instr(tax_description, 'IPI') + length('IPI'))
    ))
  ) ipi,
  (
    trim(substr(
      tax_description,
      instr(tax_description, 'ICMS') + length('ICMS'),
      instr(tax_description, '% CST') - 
        (instr(tax_description, 'ICMS') + length('ICMS'))
    ))
  ) icms,
  (
    trim(substr(
      tax_description,
      instr(tax_description, 'CST') + length('CST'),
      instr(tax_description, 'IVA') - 
        (instr(tax_description, 'CST') + length('CST'))
    ))
  ) cst,
  (
    trim(substr(
      tax_description,
      instr(tax_description, 'IVA') + length('IVA'),
      instr(tax_description, '% IVA EXT') - 
        (instr(tax_description, 'IVA') + length('IVA'))
    ))
  ) iva,
  (
    trim(substr(
      tax_description,
      instr(tax_description, 'IVA EXT') + length('IVA EXT'),
      instr(tax_description, '%', -1) - 
        (instr(tax_description, 'IVA EXT') + length('IVA EXT'))
    ))
  ) iva_ext
from tax
```

Comment: @DoubleR btw it must work fatser than regular expression approach